# Batch file - extract value with delimiter from result containing spaces

Tags: windows, batch-file

I saw similar questions but none is related to my issue.
I am using regedit to retrieve result where python is installed. I want to get this value:**C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe**

```
C:\Users\user1>reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\3.8\InstallPath /V ExecutablePath

    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\3.8\InstallPath
    ExecutablePath    REG_SZ    C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe
```

Now I wrote a script:

```
SET PYTHON_PATH_SEARCH=reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\3.8\InstallPath /V ExecutablePath

FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims= " %%A IN ('%PYTHON_PATH_SEARCH%') DO (
    CALL :set_python_path %%C

)
:set_python_path
SET PYTHON_PATH=%1
exit /B 0
```

But the result is:  **C:\Program**
The issue is that I am delimiting it using the spaces but I have a space in my desired output.

Thanks in advance~

Comment: Use `tokens=1,2,*` Token `*` is *the remainder, after the highest nominated token number* AND `call :set_... "%%C"` Then `%~1`. Quoting combines a space-infused string into a single string. `~` removes the outer set of quotes from a metavariable. Use `set "var=value"` for setting string values - this avoids problems caused by trailing spaces. Don't assign `"` or a terminal backslash or Space. Build pathnames from the elements - counterintuitively, it is likely to make the process easier.

Comment: @Magoo thanks for your `prompt` assistance, but still the same output:
`"FOR /F "tokens=1,2,* delims= " %%A IN ('%PYTHON_PATH_SEARCH%') DO (
    CALL :set_python_path %%C
)"`
result: `Path found C:\Program`

Comment: @Magoo sorry - checking this extended solution by you now...

Comment: @Magoo it seems its working. I am just unsure for this part 'use `set "var=value"`'. In which contest you were targeting this?

Comment: Generally, for a `set` statement where the value assigned is a string. `SET "PYTHON_PATH=%~1"` for instance. If there are trailing spaces on the code line, it can cause hard-to-find problems if the trailing space is included in the value assigned. The quotes prevent this. Once bitten, twice shy.

Comment: @Magoo thanks, please provide this as answer so I could mark it :) thanks a lot...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `tokens=1,2,*`

Token `*` is the remainder, after the highest nominated token number

AND `call :set_... "%%C"` Then `%~1` in the subroutine.

Quoting combines a space-infused string into a single string.

`~` removes the outer set of quotes from a metavariable.

Use `set "var=value"` for setting string values - this avoids problems caused by trailing spaces. Don't assign `"` or a terminal `\` or <kbd>Space</kbd>. Build pathnames from the elements - counterintuitively, it is likely to make the process easier